# How to hide a link if the user has no posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to hide a link if the user has no posts.
I tried a lot of snippets but still not working ????

Here's the link that I try to hide: `<a class="btn btn-success author-link" href="<?php $user_info = get_currentuserinfo(); echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $user_info->ID ) ); ?>" rel="author">View all posts</a>`

**EDIT:**
I think I found something:

```
    <?php function count_userposts( $userid ) 
{$args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => array( 'post', 'article_type' ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'author'        => $userid
    );
    $counter_posters = count( get_posts( $args ) ); 
    return $counter_posters; } ?>
<?php if(count_userposts(wp_get_current_user()->ID)) { ?>
<a class="btn btn-success author-link" href="<?php $user_info = get_currentuserinfo(); echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $user_info->ID ) ); ?>" rel="author">View all posts</a>
<?php } else { ?>
b
<?php } ?>
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: U need to add more code about the posts. I think `if(count($allPosts) > 0){// write your code here}` but problem is that where u define posts

Comment: [count author posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) and do `if($user_post > 0)`

Comment: Thanks, I think I found a way to the hide the link ! I don't know if it's the best solution but it works !

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:-

```
<?php
if(count_user_posts( get_current_user_id() ) > 0) :
?>
<a class="btn btn-success author-link" href="<?php $user_info = get_currentuserinfo(); echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $user_info->ID ) ); ?>" rel="author">View all posts</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this ll work ..

```
<?php
  while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    // Display post
    if ( have_posts() ): // If this is the last post, the loop will    start over// Do something if this isn't the last post
    endif;
 endwhile;
?>
```